# Can't checkout remote branch using GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, github-desktop

When I first clone a repo using GitHub Desktop (windows version), I'm able to see all of the branches and can checkout the branches.

However, if another contributor creates a new remote branch (after I've done the clone), GitHub Desktop isn't able to fetch and checkout the new branches. The branches are visible via the GitHub website. The only way I've found to checkout these branches via GitHub desktop is to delete the local repo and clone again. I was expecting the "Sync" button to handle fetching new branches from the remote repo.

Any ideas?

Comment: Another thing to add: If I use the git command line client to pull changes from the remote repo, the branches then appear in GitHub desktop

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to Steve Ward at GitHub Support:

> You should be able to hit F5 in GitHub Desktop to refresh the repository and fetch any new branches from the remote repository. There currently aren't any animations for this process, but it should work without issue. [...] we automatically fetch new branches every five minutes as well.

Comment: wow, that really worked! do you have a source of the message or is that from a private chat?

Comment: @SeriousM it was an email thread generated from a customer support ticket, yes.

Comment: F5 worked for me. It doesn't seem to be fetching new branches on an interval though. Would be nice to see this supported better. I also expected sync to do it.

Comment: It was last year... why isn't this still a GUI functionality? The very purpose of a GUI is to make common tasks accessible for non-command line users (I use the command line but not as much on Windows). It's weird that `git fetch` is then so obscure. No wonder most repo GUIs are a failure.

Answer (score 5):

You can also click on the "Gear" button in upper right of the client, select "Open in Git Shell" and type the command git fetch in the command window that is opened...

Comment: Thank you, you saved the day